# Find out SMTP of organization o365 Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, smtp

I have been wondering how to find a SMTP host on an Organization/School Office 365 account. This is because "Mail Flow" blocks any messages to GMail, Hotmail, Yahoo, etc. If I can set up a program that will forward any emails with a specific word in the title to a GMail email, the email will end up getting from Office 365 -> program that forwards emails -> GMail.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be as easy as setting up [email forwarding](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Forward-email-to-another-email-account-1ed4ee1e-74f8-4f53-a174-86b748ff6a0e) in Office 365.

You can set up  [specific rules](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Forward-messages-automatically-with-a-rule-e5bfd2f7-921b-43c4-a9f1-15834cf6950e) for forwarding. Here you might be able to set up a rule based on the subject of the email.